# What is the relationship between $W_1$ and $W_2$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

I have a model which schematic is in the linked picture. Blue $A$ and $B$ are rotational joints, black and red shapes are rigid elements. $I_1$ is moment of inertia of black and red elements combined with $\vec{W_1}$ reference axis and $I_2$ is moment of inertia of red element with $\vec{W_2}$ reference axis. An electrical motor is attached to black element. Motors rotor is connected to red element. I want to know dynamics of how $\vec{W_1}$ depends on $\vec{W_2}$.

Will it be just:

$I_1\vec{W_1} + I_2\vec{W_2} = \vec{0}$

and this equation derivative, due to angular momentum conservation law?

[image: Model schematic]

Comment: Why was this closed? The author asks if conservation of momentum can be used in articulated mechanisms. This is a valid question, maybe poorly worded.

Comment: I am not arguing over quality of my English, as I am not a native speaker, but I do not understand why this topic was "put on hold" though. I also do not know why this question was considered "Homework-like question", but nevertheless I provided probable solution which I consider to be "some effort".

Comment: I agree, and that is why I nominated it for re-open.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why this close reason was chosen, but as it stands this is pretty much Unclear What You're Asking. I know it's hard for non-native English speakers, but you should clarify the question and it will help give it its best shot at an answer once it's reopened.

Comment: I want to know if angular momentum conservation law apply to described system as i presented it in original question. This will allow me to model this system with a set of differential equations. Please tell me if system schematic is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Are you are asking for the *kinematics* and not the *dynamics* of the two joints?

The first joint is simple $$\vec{\omega}_1 = \hat{j} \dot{q}_1$$

where $\dot{q}_i$ is the speed of the i-th joint. Now notice that the second joint is oriented along

$$\hat{z}_2 = {\rm R}_Y(q_1) {\rm R}_Z(a) \hat{j}$$ where ${\rm R}_\square$ are elementary rotation matrices. The rotational velocity of the second joint is thus

$$ \vec{\omega}_2 = \vec{\omega}_1 + \hat{z} \dot{q}_2 $$

Comment: No, I am looking for red and black element dynamics. I need to model this system with set of differential equations. It is a part of greater dynamic system Twin-Rotor Aerodynamic System. Black element illustrates body of system, and red element is one of the propellers.